# getting full path of a file that is located at ftp server using java

Tags: java

how to get the full path of a file that is located at an ftp server using java (is it possible to get path using sinetfactory api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, as there is no convention for mapping ftp server trees to physical file names.